# How do I use a tensorflow loss function with a keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using Tensorflow 1.14, and I have designed a model using Keras. I want to use `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` when I compile my model, but I do not see any equivalent loss function in Keras. Is there any way I can use this with my model?

My current code to compile:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tf.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy` with `from_logits` set to `True` and wrap it in a function

```
import tensorflow as tf

def my_tf_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=True)

model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50()
model.compile(loss=my_tf_loss_fn, optimizer='adam')
```

But if you insist on using `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`
I cannot think of a clean way to do this, but this works

```
import tensorflow as tf

def my_tf_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred)

model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50()
dummy_tensor = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None])
model.compile(loss=my_tf_loss_fn, optimizer='adam', target_tensors=dummy_tensor)
```